# WSO2 ESB: header set in "in sequence" lost in "out sequence"

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm having a huge problem with message mediation in WSO2. Here's the thing.

In my insequence, I set a transport header in my message, containing the messageID, this way :

```
<property name="MediationMessageId" scope="transport" expression="get-property('MessageID')"/>
```

Now, I want to access this property in the outsequence. But when I try to access it in my payloadFactory, all i've got is an empty string:

```
<payloadFactory media-type="json">
    <format>{"mediationmessageid": "$1"}</format>
    <args>
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:MediationMessageId"/>
    </args>
</payloadFactory>
```

Results in:

```
{"mediationmessageid": ""}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks a lot

EDIT: the in sequence and the out sequence are in 2 separate files. Don't know if this could have an impact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A transport header will be gone after using a call or send mediator to call a backend service. The backend sets it's own transport (Response) headers on the response.

If you want your value still available after the call/send mediator you need to set it for example at the Synapse (default scope). This exists for the whole transaction.  You can either specify 'default' as scope or not specify it at all and it will be set to Synapse.

If you also need the property to be send with your message as a transport header (which is what the transport scope does) you will have to set it twice. Once in the default scope and once as a transport header. For example:

```
<property name="X-MediationMessageId" scope="transport" expression="get-property('MessageID')"/>
<property name="MediationMessageId" scope="default" expression="get-property('MessageID')"/>
```

And to retrieve then use:

```
<payloadFactory media-type="json">
    <format>{"mediationmessageid": "$1"}</format>
    <args>
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:MediationMessageId"/>
    </args>
</payloadFactory>
```

For more about scope check [wso2 documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Property+Mediator)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that's the conclusion I got to after a good night of sleep.
Marking this as the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok after a lot a sweat and tears, I finally vanquished the monster.

Here is the working configuration for the in sequence:

```
<property expression="get-property('MessageID')" name="MediationMessageId" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

And the one for the out sequence:

```
<payloadFactory media-type="json">
    <format>{"MediationMessageId": "$1"}</format>
    <args>
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('default', 'MediationMessageId')"/>
    </args>
</payloadFactory>
```

It was just a confusion on the scopes of the properties...

Thanks to everyone who read and had a thought about this question.

Answer (score 0):

your property is in the normal scope, not in the transportscope (where the message headers etc. are) so you should access it like this: 
`$ctx:MediationMessageId`

Also there is a typo, you defined your property with CamelCase while trying to access with all lowercase :)

Comment: Wait, why is my property in the normal scope, when I specify "scope=transport" ?

Comment: Anyway, I made the changes to CamelCase and default score, it's not giving any result either.
I've edited my question to highlight the fact that my in and out sequences are in 2 separate files, I don't know if this could have an impact on the solution.